# Could not compile build file 'C:\Users\Hp\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\android\app\build.gradle'

Tags: android, visual-studio-code

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\Hp\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\android\app\build.gradle' line: 1
- What went wrong:
  Could not compile build file 'C:\Users\Hp\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\android\app\build.gradle'.

> startup failed:
> build file 'C:\Users\Hp\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\android\app\build.gradle': 1: unable to resolve class io.flutter.GradleException
> @ line 1, column 1.
> import io.flutter.GradleException
> ^

1 error

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1